# How to use sed to remove dots between 2 patterns

Tags: sed

I've a file with the following text:

```
<RecordID>02.037.D00221700080.0</RecordID>
2.35
AB
<RecordID>02.037.D00221700080.1</RecordID>
2.45
BB
<RecordID>02.037.D00221700080.2</RecordID>
6.5
CC
```

I wish to remove the dots, between `<RecordID>` and `</RecordID>` to get this:

```
<RecordID>02037D002217000800</RecordID>
2.35
AB
<RecordID>02037D002217000801</RecordID>
2.45
BB
<RecordID>02037D002217000802</RecordID>
6.5
CC
```

I've tried different approaches with sed, all of them without results...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe '/RecordID/ and tr/.//d;' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```sh
sed '/<RecordID>/s/\.//g' file

<RecordID>02037D002217000800</RecordID>
2.35
AB
<RecordID>02037D002217000801</RecordID>
2.45
BB
<RecordID>02037D002217000802</RecordID>
6.5
CC
```

Comment: Yes! Works fine! Thanks! I was driving crazy to find the right regexp...